# Can I play Skylanders: Trap Team on the Wii-U with two Pro controllers?

Tags: wii-u, skylanders-trap-team

I would like to play Skylanders: Trap Team on the WiiU with two pro controllers, but no matter what I do the game seems to insist that the game be played with one player on the gamepad and the other player on a controller.

Is there a way to disable the Gamepad so that I can use two Pro controllers to play?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use the giant controller with the giant screen?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to get the gamepad out off range of the Wii console.
As soon as the connection is broken the second controller can be used.

Disclaimer: I do not have pro controllers only normal wii remotes but I suspect it works the same for pro controllers.